# Laravel convert timestamp into date with specific timezone

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, php-carbon

I am saving my timestamp in Laravel using the following.

```
Carbon::now()->timestamp;
```

How do you convert a timestamp into a specific time format with a specific timezone (using Carbon)?

```
$unix_time_stamp = "1572095520";
$date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($unix_time_stamp);
$date->setTimezone('Pacific/Auckland')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

I am getting incorrect result on this one, should be Oct 27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the following.

```php
$unix_time_stamp = '1572095520';
$converted = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($unix_time_stamp,'Pacific/Auckland')
    ->toDateTimeString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to config -> app.php and change 'timezone' => 'Pacific/Auckland',

Comment: this will default the timezone for NZ, however on my problem users have different timezones. Anyway I appreciate your effort, thanks! :) the above answer works